# How to use Symfony Widgets in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to use this widget in my datafield:

```
'widget' => 'single_text',
```

but i can't insert in my code:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="purchasedate", type="date")
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = "2019-01-14",
 *      max = "2019-04-14"
 * )
 * 
 * 
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("purchasedate")
 * @Serializer\Expose()
 * 
 */

private $purchasedate;
```

[How the field is suppose to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDPlo.png)

[How it's now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW3Cd.png)

How i'm building the form :

```
  <div class="form-group col-12">
        {{ form_widget(form.user.purchasedate, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control required',
        'placeholder': 'Date d’achat (JJ/MM/AAAA)*', 'maxlength': 13}})}}
        {% if form_errors(form.user.purchasedate) %}<span class="error-form">{{
            form_errors(form.user.purchasedate) }}</span>{% endif %}
    </div>
```

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gIWu.png)
[PatricipationType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5s7o.png)

Comment: How are you building your form? The form rendering is usually not controlled by the Entity itself, but a separate FormType class or in some cases by building the form dynamically in the controller. Where are you setting the widget type?

Comment: I update the question with the code im using to build the form

Comment: Thanks, but this only shows how the form is rendered in your template. I would like to see the FormType-class in your php code. How do you build the form-variable that is being passed to the view? Can you maybe show the controller-action? It will be easier to guide you from there.

Comment: Check if its the " PHP ACTION " image that i put

Comment: No, sorry but this is not what I meant. Can you show the code from the controller?

Comment: ohhh okay, check now

Comment: Can you now also show the code of the `ParticipationType` class and of the probably nested custom form types?

Comment: okay, check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put it in the formType like this:

```
$builder->add('purchasedate', DateType::class, array(
  'widget' => 'single_text',
  'html5' => false,
));
```

In your case `$purchasedate` is a property of `User` class, so it should be added to `UserType` form type class.